# What culture does this duality symbol belong to?

Tags: symbolism, iconography

While browsing today I came upon this symbol tagged as duality, but I am unable to identify it.

[image]

Does anybody recognize where this symbol comes from? Is it part of a culture/religion or just something an artist doodled?

Comment: [Venn Diagram](https://www.imageidentify.com/result/0siohraxzslze)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it would be possible to know for certain unless we ask the artist who drew it, but the symbol looks like a very simplified version of the Chinese [taijitu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taijitu),  the "[yin and yang symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang)":

[image: yin and yang symbol]

Comment: Yeh I think it's a venn diagram of taijitu. Thanks